# PyQt QScrollArea doesn't display widgets

Tags: python-3.x, scrollbar, pyqt5

I am somewhat new to GUI programming and very new to PyQt, and I'm trying to build a GUI that displays a list of questions. I have created a `QuestionBank` class that subclasses `QWidget` and overrides the `.show()` method to display the list properly. I have tested this alone and it works correctly. However, the list of questions can be quite long, so I've been trying to make it scrollable. Rather than add a `QScrollBar` to the widget and then set up the event triggers by hand, I've been trying to my `QuestionBank` widget in a `QScrollArea` based on the syntax I've seen in examples online. While the scroll area shows up fine, it does not at all display the question bank but rather just shows a blank outline.

The `QuestionBank` class looks like this:

```
class QuestionBank(QWidget):
    BUFFER = 10 # space between questions (can be modified)
    def __init__(self, parent, questions):
        # `parent` should be the QWidget that contains the QuestionBank, or None if
        # QuestionBank is top level

        # `questions` should be a list of MasterQuestion objects (not widgets)
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.questions = [MasterQuestionWidget(self, q) for q in questions]
        self.bottomEdge = 0

    def show(self, y=BUFFER):
        QWidget.show(self)

        for q in self.questions:
            # coordinates for each each question
            q.move(QuestionBank.BUFFER, y)
            q.show()
            # update y-coordinate so that questions don't overlap
            y += q.frameGeometry().height() + QuestionBank.BUFFER
        self.bottomEdge = y + 3 * QuestionBank.BUFFER
    # ... other methods down here
```

My code for showing the scroll bar looks like this:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

frame = QScrollArea()
qs = QuestionBank(None, QFileManager.importQuestions())
qs.resize(350, 700)
frame.setGeometry(0, 0, 350, 300)
frame.setWidget(qs)
frame.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have tried many variants of this, including calling `resize` on `frame` instead of `qs`, getting rid of `setGeometry`, and setting the parent of `qs` to `frame` instead of `None` and I have no idea where I'm going wrong.

If it helps, I'm using `PyQt5`

Here is the question bank without the scroll area, to see what it is supposed to look like:
[image: The question bank without a scroll area, with random questions in it]

Here is the output of the code above with the scroll area:
[image: The question bank with a scroll area]

This variation on the code is the only one that produces any output whatsoever, the rest just have blank windows. I'm convinced its something simple I'm missing, as the frame is obviously resizing correctly and it obviously knows what widget to display but its not showing the whole thing.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: If you replace `QuestionBank(None, QFileManager.importQuestions())` with another widget it works correctly, so maybe the problem is in QuestionBank but that class is impossible to test since it is not complete.

Comment: @eyllanesc the `MasterQuestionWidget` class (used inside `QuestionBank`) is just a subclass of `QLabel` so I replaced `self.questions = [MasterQuestionWidget(self, q) for q in questions]` with `self.questions = [QLabel("words", self) for q in questions]` and it still shows up with the same  problem

Comment: Edit your question and add everything necessary to make it a [mcve] :P